Where to find variance estimates for sample size/power calculations
I am working on a grant application. I am attempting to calculate required sample size for a crossover, entirely within-subject design, where all participants will be exposed to four conditions, placebo and three other formulations of a drug (order counterbalanced). Participants will have the outcome of interest measured four times per day for seven days for each of the four conditions. So for each participant there are 4 x 7 x 4 = 112 measurements. We are going to compare each of the three formulations of the drug to placebo.
I am using the R package simr to estimate required sample size based on this design. It has a nifty function called makeLMER where you create the predictors and grouping variables in a dataset but leave out the outcome. I started with 20 participants, so 20 x 112 = 2240 observations of this unspecified outcome. The user has to enter in the estimated effects, then another function estimates power. I supply R code for creating the data structure here. Sincere apologies to non-R users, and for the code making the question longer, but I thought I'd supply it just in case it helps someone who is familiar with the package, and to illustrate the structure. But the code is not necessary for my question at the end of the post.
library(dplyr)

daysPerCondition <- 1:7
measurementsPerDay <- 1:4
participants <- 1:20
nObsPerParticipant <- length(conditions)*length(daysPerCondition)*length(measurementsPerDay)
totalObs <- length(participants)*nObsPerParticipant

# now create dataset
d <- tibble(id = factor(rep(x=participants,
                            each=nObsPerParticipant)),
            condition = rep(x=conditions,
                            each=length(daysPerCondition)*length(measurementsPerDay),
                            length.out = totalObs),
            day = rep(x=daysPerCondition,
                      each=length(measurementsPerDay),
                      length.out=totalObs),
            measurement = rep(x=measurementsPerDay,
                              length.out=totalObs))

head(d)

#output
 id    condition   day measurement
  <fct> <fct>     <int>       <int>
1 1     placebo       1           1
2 1     placebo       1           2
3 1     placebo       1           3
4 1     placebo       1           4
5 1     placebo       2           1
6 1     placebo       2           2

I am powering the study on three comparisons: each of the three formulations compared to placebo. Apologies again to non-R users but the lme4 syntax for this would be lmer(formula = y ~ condition + (1|id)) where condition is a four-level factor and id is the indicator variable for participant id. The makeLmer function requires the user to supply values for the effects. From literature I have determined the average score on a 0-100 visual analog pain severity scale people with chronic neuropathic pain in a placebo condition to be 24.2. A meta-analysis determined the minimum clinically significant difference to be 10. The model I am going to use is a random-intercepts repeated measures regression, the makeLmer() function also requires the user to estimate the variance of the intercepts, which I found from the standard error of the intercept coefficient reported in a another pain paper. Finally you are required to estimate the residual variance. I have chosen 5 so now I can create my simulated model.
library(simr)

# specify effects
b <- c(24.2, -10, -10, -10) # fixed effects, intercept and three difference estimates
V1 <- 4.1 # intercept variance
s <- 5 # residual variance

# simulate data 
model1 <- makeLmer(formula = y ~ condition + (1|id), 
                   fixef=b, 
                   VarCorr=V1
                   sigma=s, 
                   data=d)

print(model1)

# output
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']

Formula: y ~ condition + (1 | id)
   Data: d
REML criterion at convergence: 14129.64
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 2.025   
 Residual             5.000   
Number of obs: 2240, groups:  id, 20
Fixed Effects:
     (Intercept)  conditionthcOnly   conditionthccbd  conditioncbdonly  
            24.2             -10.0             -10.0             -10.0 

Now we have a 'pilot' model that we can calculate the power for using the powerSim() function
powerSim(model1, nsim=20)

#output
Power for predictor 'condition', (95% confidence interval):

    100.0% (83.16, 100.0)

Test: Likelihood ratio

Based on 20 simulations, (1 warning, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 2240

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 3 s

So with 20 participants, and admittedly a lot of measurements, and with the effect sizes and variances specified we have 100% power to detect the effect. This seems grossly inflated to me. I wonder what I might be doing wrong. I'm quite confident about the fixed effects I specified but am not so sure about the variances I specified.
So (finally) we get to my question.
1. How or where would I find a good estimate of residual variance? It is not the sort of thing they publish in papers. You tend to get (at best) standard errors of regression coefficients.
2. Am I specifying the variance of intercepts correctly? I just entered the standard error of an intercept coefficient I got from a paper. Should I be squaring this to get the variance?
Any help much appreciated. Please let me know if any more details needed.


How or where would I find a good estimate of residual variance?

This is often difficult, as you have discovered. Here are a few ideas:

Look in the appendices to relevant papers. I have seen model output published in appendices before (but not often).
For very similar designs, if they don't publish the details you need, then contact the authors and ask. In my experience if you can find papers where one of the authors is a PhD student, they are often very happy to help, especially if you appeal to their ego !
Make some "informed guesses". Contact some experienced researchers in your institution and wherever you have contacts, and ask for advice.


Am I specifying the variance of intercepts correctly?

Yes, that's correct.
Why are the power estimations so high ?
This might be caused by serial dependence. This is very important because
when measurements taken only a few hours apart often result in serial dependence and if it is present and not accounted for, you will be underestimating the amount of noise in your measurements, which could lead to the overly optimistic power estimates you have obtained. As far as I know (and I don't know a lot about it) simr does not provide a way to do this. You might need to employ a different approach, such as:

making your own power calculations. Normally I would suggest using an unstructured covariance matrix for the residual error covariance. However, with a large number of time points this will require a lot of parameters to be estimated, specifically $\frac{t(t+1)}{2}$ where $t$ is the number of time points. So in this case, with 112 measurements for each participants it would be 6,328. It would be surprising if you were able to fit such a model. Other possibilities are AR(1) (2 parameters for the homogenous case and $t+1$ for the heterogeneous case), Toeplitz ($k$ for the homogenous case, and $k+t$ for the heterogeneous case, where $k$ is the number of covariance parameters). Other structures are also possible and you can find details of these in the following threads:

How to handle the residual covariance structure in a mixed model with repeated measurements?
Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures

consider a different approach entirely. One alternative is the discrete time Markov ordinal longitudinal state transition model. Frank Harrell has written a lot about these models and you can read about them on his websites:

https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19/ordmarkov
https://www.fharrell.com/talk/icsa/
https://www.fharrell.com/talk/cmstat/

Another possible approach is Generalised Least Squares. Again, Frank has written about these, as have many others:

https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long
https://www.fharrell.com/post/re/index.html
https://www.uh.edu/~bsorense/GLS_May_2017.pdf
